# Custom Date and Time in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to wrap my head around a custom date control system. I have this for advancing time on Unity:

```
        private void AdvanceTime() {
        if (paused) return;
        currentTimer -= Time.deltaTime * (fastForwarding ? fastForwardMultiplier : 1f);
        if(currentTimer <= 0) {
            currentTimer += dayDuration;
            dayPassed++;
        }
    }
```

I am calling this method on Update method and it works.
My question is, how can I get custom dates like this?For the project I'm on, I'll ignore months but will introduce seasons (60days) as months. If I start with a random Date like 13 Spring 420, how can I get what I want?

I don't know if it's a proper question. Actually it's my first here. 
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You're probably going to have to write an adapter for this, that internally holds a datetime, but is able to convert months to seasons, and vice versa

Comment: Why are you using date time library? You just need a float. And write your own logic. DateTime is not helping you here in any way.

Comment: Actually I don't know DateTime class at all, I looked it up and I believe that'd be an overkill like @user14492 said. Currently I have ongoing days that elapses each second (or a duration I can pass).

Comment: So what's the question then? Also have a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html

Comment: @user14492 How can I get a Date like day/season/year format? I am kind of bad at math.

Comment: No. There's nothing that already exists. You'll have to create your own based on floats or DateTime depending on what kind of manipulations you wish to do.

Comment: I don't know what kind of manipulations we are talking about here. And "No" is not a valid answer to what I asked tbh :)

Comment: Need some bits of information to provide you with an algorithm for this. 

Are you wanting to have the seasons within the game based on real world time? 

To clarify format you are wanting is the following: x/60 days, Season, Year? 

Will fast forwarding need to offset the real world or days within the game?

Comment: What does "13 Spring 420" mean? Is it 13 days into the 420th Spring? Could you let us know what number of daysPassed 13 Spring 420 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what `13 Spring 420` means, but here's how you could turn the amount of days into a year/season/day format. I'm assuming `dayPassed` is the total amount of days (plural) that have passed.

## Getting the days in a year/season/day format

We'll start by getting the year, we can call it `year`. To get the value we want, we divide the `dayPassed` with the amount of days in a year and round down. If we do an [integer division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division) the rounding is already taken care of for us.

```cs
int year = dayPassed / amountOfDaysInYear;
```

To get the season number we need to divide the **remaining days** after the last calculation (we can call this variable `yearRemainder`) by the season length (in your case, 60). We can get the remainder of a division with the [remainder operator `%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) (also known as the modulo operator).

```cs
int yearRemainder = dayPassed % amountOfDaysInYear;
int season = yearRemainder / amountOfDaysInSeason;
```

Finally, the remaining days will just be the **remainder** from the previous calculation.

```cs
int day = yearRemainder % amountOfDaysInSeason;
```

### An example

I'll give it a quick rundown with an example. Let's say we are trying to get day 703 in a year/season/day format. A year is 240 days long and a season is 60 days long.

```
year = 703 / 240           // = 2
yearRemainder = 703 % 240  // = 223
season = 223 / 60          // = 3
day = 223 % 60             // = 43
```

So the answer is that it's year `2`, season `3` (0-indexed), and day `43`.

We can double check by making sure the years, seasons and days add up.

```
2 * 240 = 480
3 * 60  = 180
43 * 1  = 43

480 + 180 + 43 = 703
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for answer, I did find a way to increment and control days. It's similar to yours but it's progressive. I don't calculate it via total days passed, but yours will solve a problem with serialization, so thank you.

Comment: @MrPaparoz would you mind posting your solution as an answer to your question? I'm curious to see how you got it to work.

Comment: @SpencerStream I did.

Answer (score 1):

this is controller:

```
public class TimeController : MonoBehaviour {
        public const string DateChanged = "DateChanged";
        [Header("Settings")]
        [SerializeField] private Date date;
        [SerializeField, Range(1, 10)] private float timeScale = 1f;
        [SerializeField, Range(2, 32)] private int fastForwardModifier = 4;
        [SerializeField] private bool paused;
        [SerializeField] private bool fastForwarding;
        [Header("Properties")]
        [SerializeField, ReadOnly] private int totalDaysPassed;

        public bool Paused { get { return paused; } }
        public bool FastForwarding { get { return fastForwarding; } }

        private float timer;

        private void OnEnable() {
            date = new Date();
        }

        private void Start() {
            InitializeTimer();
        }

        private void InitializeTimer() {
            timer = timeScale;
        }

        private void Update() {
            AdvanceTime();
        }

        private void AdvanceTime() {
            if(paused) return;
            timer -= Time.deltaTime * (fastForwarding ? fastForwardModifier : 1);
            if(timer <= 0) {
                timer += timeScale;
                OnDayPassed();
            }
        }

        private void OnDayPassed() {
            totalDaysPassed++;
            date.AdvanceDay();
            this.PostEvent(DateChanged, new OnDateChanged(date));
        }

        public void PauseOrResume() {
            paused = !paused;
        }
    }

    public class OnDateChanged : EventData {
        public Date Date { get; private set; }

        public OnDateChanged(Date date) {
            Date = date;
        }
    }
```

this is Date class:

```
    public enum Seasons {
    Spring = 1,
    Summer = 2,
    Autumn = 3,
    Winter = 4

}
[System.Serializable]
public class Date {
    [Header("General")]
    [SerializeField, ReadOnly] private int DaysInMonth = 29;
    [SerializeField, Min(1)] private float day;
    [SerializeField, Min(1)] private int season;
    [SerializeField, Min(1)] private int year;

    public float Day { get => day; private set => day = value; }
    public int Season { get => season; private set => season = value; }
    public int Year { get => year; private set => year = value; }

    public Seasons currentSeason;

    public Date(int startDay = 1, int startSeason = 1, int startYear = 420) {
        Day = startDay;
        Season = startSeason;
        currentSeason = (Seasons)Season;
        Year = startYear;
    }

    public void AdvanceDay() {
        Day++;
        if(Day > DaysInMonth) {
            Day = 1;
            AdvanceSeason();
        }
    }

    private void AdvanceSeason() {
        Season++;
        currentSeason = (Seasons)Season;
        if(Season > 4) {
            Season = 1;
            AdvanceYear();
        }
    }

    public Seasons GetCurrentSeason() {
        return (Seasons)Season;
    }

    private void AdvanceYear() {
        Year++;
    }
}
```

}